# How to handle different types of items

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game for unity with the grid-based inventory system, but I have a problem. I don't know how to handle different types of items in the inventory.

e.g

I have a class `Item`:

```
class Item
{
    public int ID;
    public string name;
}
```

then I have weapon class that inherits Item class

```
class Weapon: Item
{
    public int damage;
}
```

and material class

```
class Material : Item
{
    public int hardness;
}
```

and my question is how to put them in the same list like `List<Item> inventory`, and still access all their properties. Is this a good way to approach this or do I need a completely different system?

Comment: [Downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is` and `as` C# operators to find out and cast your objects to their derived type. See the following example:

```
class Item
{
    public int ID;
    public string name;
}

class Weapon : Item
{
    public int damage;
}

class Material : Item
{
    public int hardness;
}


void Main()
{
    List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
    inventory.Add(new Weapon
    {
        name = "weapon",
        ID = 1,
        damage = 10,
    });


    inventory.Add(new Material
    {
        name = "material",
        ID = 1,
        hardness = 100,
    });

    foreach (var item in inventory)
    {
        if (item is Weapon)
        {
            var weapon = item as Weapon;
            weapon.Dump();
        }
        if (item is Material)
        {
            var material = item as Material;
            material.Dump();
        }
    }

}
```

You can see more examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-safely-cast-by-using-as-and-is-operators).